# unpack each element of an array into a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

So I have a `constexpr` `array`, is there a way to templatize each of its elements as a template parameter, the purpose is that so I can call a function of each of them, but instead of a loop which is runtime, I'd like to call it at compile time, also be able to use `static_assert` on it? So far I tried the following but it didn't work, the compiler couldn't deduce the proper parameter to the func. I'm using version c++17.

```
template <auto param, typename Function, typename... Args>
void invoke_param(Function func, Args... args)
{
    func(param, args...);
}

template <auto... params, typename Function, typename... Args>
void invoke_params(Function func, Args... args)
{
    (invoke_param<params>(func, args...), ...);
}

template <auto& Array, std::size_t... Indices, typename Function, typename... Args>
auto for_each_array_impl(std::index_sequence<Indices...>, Function func, Args... args)
{
    invoke_params<Array[Indices]...>(func, args...);
}

template <auto& Array, typename Function, typename... Args>
auto for_each_array(Function func, Args... args)
{
    return for_each_array_impl<Array>(
        std::make_index_sequence<std::size(Array)>(), func, args...);
}

static constexpr std::array<int, 5> ARR{1,2,3,4,5};
int main() {
    auto fun = []<int E>() {
        static_assert(E > 0);
        //...;
    };
    for_each_array<ARR>(func);
}
```

Comment: `[]<int E>` is a C++20 syntax, whereas your question is tagged c++17. Which one do you actually need?

Comment: `fun` in your example is not a callable: `fun()` doesn't compile. Its `operator()` has a non-deducible template parameter. If you are willing to call it as `func.template operator()<param>(args...);` then [this compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/r5sfM5bWW)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `param` as a template parameter if you want it to be a template parameter

```
template <auto param, typename Function, typename... Args>
void invoke_param(Function func, Args... args)
{
    func.template operator()<param>(args...);
}
```

As an aside, you need C++20 for `[]<int E>()`, before then you'd have to write it longhand.

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f36dbe93df248c1e)

Comment: thanks, but why i have to use `func.template operator()` instead of `func(...)`, how can I then pass other kinds of callables as func, like a result of `bind`?

Comment: @fluter because that's the syntax for member templates. There's nothing to deduce `E` from, it has to be passed explicitly

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 we can condense all the boilerplate down into a single function thanks to template lambdas and expanded auto parameters:

### [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vjxGr4vva)

```
template<auto& arr, auto F>
consteval auto for_each_array()
{
    []<auto... indices>(std::index_sequence<indices...>)
    {
        (F.template operator()<arr[indices]>(), ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<arr.size()>{});
}


static constexpr std::array<int, 5> ARR{1,2,3,4,5};
int main() {
    constexpr auto fun = []<int E>()
    {
        static_assert(E > 0);
        //...
    };

    for_each_array<ARR, fun>();
}
```

`for_each_array` creates a helper lambda and immediately invokes it, making use of a fold-expression to call your function for each array value.

---

EDIT:

### [C++17 version](https://godbolt.org/z/KMc17EnTj)

```
template<auto& arr, class F, auto... indices>
constexpr auto for_each_array_impl(F callable, std::index_sequence<indices...>)
{   
    (callable.template operator()<arr[indices]>(), ...);
}

template<auto& arr, class F>
constexpr auto for_each_array(F&& callable)
{
    for_each_array_impl<arr>(std::forward<F>(callable),
                        std::make_index_sequence<arr.size()>{});
}
```

Called like so:

```
struct fun
{
    template <int E>
    void operator()()
    {
        static_assert(E > 0);
        //...
    }
};

static constexpr std::array<int, 5> ARR{1,2,3,4,5};
int main() {
    for_each_array<ARR>(fun{});
}
```